# Web service calling from javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new in web development i want call web service which give response in Json in my HTML page using javascript or Jquery. Also Json parsing in Javascript or Jquery.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ problem solved!

Comment: google is your friend

Comment: But don't forget [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)!

Comment: @paul-draper, let the OP try first, don't take big CORS here :p

Comment: show us what have you tried..

Comment: @Arun, if it saves him ten hours of banging his head against his computer, I feel it is a good warning, at least for a place to start.

Comment: @PaulDraper sure i appreciate you warning, Vipul, please try yourself first, although this is not right place to ask such questions,

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new in web development : **Every Expert was beginner in start.**

i want call web service which give response in Json in my HTML page using javascript or Jquery. : **most probably  [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is used here**

Also Json parsing in Javascript or Jquery. **:jQuery has already inbulit methods like [parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)**

so there are lot of options, you just need to google it in right way.